# How to access declared type in package, is it possible?

Tags: sql, plsql

When I create varray in one package, for example `type MyArray Is Varying Array(20) Of Varchar2(512);`

is it possible to access from another package (or from anywhere) `myPackage.MyArray...`??? Or how to solve the problem, that I need MyArray everywhere (can't use global type...)

Thanks!

Comment: yes u create this variable in your package specification and access it like mypackage.variable for your session. You can either use PRAGMA SERIALLY_REUSABLE;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes u create this variable in your package specification and access it like mypackage.variable for your session. You can either use PRAGMA SERIALLY_REUSABLE;